# How do I create a class that is instantiated once per request in laravel

Tags: laravel

I've created a Context class that I want to have exist once per request. I made a ServiceProvider but then I found that the kernel is created before the start of a test and it's never done again so effectively my Context class gets created once even if my test includes multiple http requests.

I want my Context class to get created at the start of each HTTP request.

I had been storing all my data in the Request class because it is created every time but that wont work when I am in a Job.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding singletons using a service container.
Or if the members of your Context class are known at compile time,
you can inject a class dependency on your controller's constructor like so:

```
class ContextController extends Controller{

   public $context;

    public function __construct(Context $context){
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function index(){
        //use $this->context
    }

}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.